# Join not working on information_schema.tables with user table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have created a table in sql server which holds names of tables in the database and some other information.  When I run this query

```
SELECT upper(TABLE_NAME) TABLE_NAME, ISNULL(syn_schema,'N') syn_schema, isnull(syn_data,'N') syn_data
FROM information_schema.tables 
left join sync_config on TABLE_NAME = TAB_NAME 
where table_type = 'BASE TABLE' 
ORDER BY TABLE_NAME
```

this returns data from the information_schema.tables but not from the sync_config tables.  syn_schema and syn_data columns are in the sync_config table.  To summarize, join is not working on both tables.  I have tried by changing datatype of tab_name column in sync_config table to SYSNAME from VARCHAR.

Thanks

Comment: Presumably the `TABLE_NAME` and `TAB_NAME` don't match exactly then. e.g. possibly leading spaces in `TAB_NAME`. Please show some example data from both tables that you think should match but isn't.

Comment: Thanks for responding on this question. Developer had added a space before the table name while saving it in the sync_config table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if the join is not working, that indicates that `TABLE_NAME = TAB_NAME` is never true.  Check the table name fields to see if they really contain what you expect. Do they match exactly, including case (even though SQL is case-insensitive when referring to a table in a query, a string comparison of table names *may** be case sensitive)?

Beyond that, post the structure and sample data of your tables for more help.

*Thanks Martin Smith.

Comment: Whether or not the match is case sensitive depends on the OP's collation.

Comment: id       TAB_NAME       SYN_SCHEMA
30  CLIENT_LIST  Y Y
31  CLIENT_RESTRICTN N
32  CYBER_DETAILS  N N
33  DAILY_RECORD  N N
34  DBA_INDEXDEFRAGLOG  N N
35  INVOICE_DETAILS  N N
36  ITEM_DETAILS  N N
37  LOGIN  N N
38  MASTER_LOGIN  N N
39  MEMBER_DETAILS  N N
40  MEMBER_DETAILS_TEMP  N N
41  MEMBER_REWARD  N N
42  MEMBER_STATISTICS  N N
43  PRINTER_DETAILS  N N
44  SCHEME_ALLOTED  N N
45  SCHEME_DETAILS  N N
46  SESSION_DETAILS  N N
47  SETUP_INVOICE  N N
48  SYNC_CONFIG  N N
49  TIMEZONE  N N
50  TRANSACTION_DETAILS  N N
51  USER_DETAILS  N N
52  USER_SECURITY  N N

Comment: @user1679692, I'm glad your problem was solved.  In the future, it is more helpful to edit your question whenever you add new information, rather than putting it here.